# Access an image from outside of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I've got couple of svg inside seperate divs.

```
<div id="divA">
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">    
     <rect x="10" y="10" height="130" width="500" style="fill: #000000"/>

     <image class="myImg" x="20" y="20" width="300" height="80"
     xlink:href="img.png" />
   </svg>
</div>
```

So basically I'm looking a way access the image which is in `divA`. How can I access `img.png` in javascript or jquery?

Comment: @RachelGallen thanks. I'm having multiple divs and each div contains an unique svg. Each svg has an image. I want to be able to use the image in the svg as well as an thumbnail out of the svg. I'm planning to use those images to create an index of each svg.

Comment: I don't know a way of doing this using client-side scripting; could you render the svg server side to a raster image and then use that image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one of the following way.

If you want to do it using div's id

```
alert($("#divA image").attr("xlink:href"));
```

Otherwise using image element's class

```
alert($(".myImg").attr("xlink:href"));
```

Please find jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7n9erkuy/

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
// i'm assume you did this with on click event
$('#divA').click(function(){

 var img = $(this).find('.myImg').attr('xlink:href');
 // do whatever you want with this value
});
```

If the `#divA` was created dynamically, then use this(i just give an option to choose just in case) :

```
// i'm assume you did this with on click event
$(document).on('click','#divA', function(){

 var img = $(this).find('.myImg').attr('xlink:href');
 // do whatever you want with this value
});
```

or you can directly access the image value like this :

```
var img = $('#divA .myImg').attr('xlink:href');
```

or store the element itself :

```
var img = $('#divA .myImg');
// then access it attributes like :
// img.attr('x'); or img.attr('width');
```

And last, after you got those value, assign it into another img, like so :

```
// this `#myNewImage` assumed you have html element with that name
$('#myNewImage').attr('xlink:href', img);
```